# Finding number of possile execution in concurrent system

Tags: concurrency

For examples If I have two processes that running concurrently and both of them have the same code

Process 1

```
1 Increase(x)
2 Decrease(x)
```

Process 2

```
1' Increase(x)
2' Decrease(x)
```

With that example, the number of possile executions are 6

[image]

My questions is that does it exist a formula that can be used to calculate this number of execution when line of code and number of threads are different?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This is a combination problem. Where n is (no of methods * no of processes) and k is no of methods.

So for your case n = (2 * 2) = 4
and k = 2

So answer will be = 4! / (2! 2!) = (4 * 3 * 2 * 1) / (2 * 2) = 6 and that's your answer from the diagram.

[For more on Combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)